# Nest JS user authentication issue with parameter name

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I am just learning nestjs for about a day and I came across this strange bug, probably has something to do with me not understanding what Im doing and rushing the project so please bear with me. My main issue is that while using JWT authentication, JSON coming from body is "username" and I can't change it. I want to log in using {"email":"test@gmail.com", "password": "password123"}, but instead it only accepts {"username":"test@gmail.com", "password": "password123"}. The word "username" is not defined or mentioned anywhere in my codebase

users.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Param, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService} from './users.service';
import { CreateUserDto} from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('/users')
export class UsersController {
  // constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  constructor(private readonly userService: UsersService) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('username')
  getUserByEmail(@Param() param) {
    return this.userService.getUserByEmail(param.email);
  }
  @Post('register')
  registerUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.userService.registerUser(createUserDto);
  }
}
```

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HashService } from './hash.service';
import { User, UserDocument} from '../schemas/user.schema'

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model < UserDocument > , private hashService: HashService) {}

  async getUserByEmail(email: string) {
    return this.userModel.findOne({
        email
      })
      .exec();
  }

  async registerUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    // validate DTO

    const createUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
    // check if user exists
    const user = await this.getUserByEmail(createUser.email);
    if (user) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    // Hash Password
    createUser.password = await this.hashService.hashPassword(createUser.password);

    return createUser.save();
  }
}
```

auth.controller.ts

```
import { AuthService} from './auth.service';
import { Controller, Request, UseGuards, Post} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post(`/login`)
  async login(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.user, "here")
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
}
```

Here is the source code https://github.com/networkdavit/pillicam_test
Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

I tried changing all the parameter names, user schemas, adding a DTO, I googled how to add a custom parameter name or override it, tried to find if "default username param" actually exists. Nothing has worked for me so far

Answer (score 0):

It's in there `username` in your code. [https://github.com/networkdavit/pillicam_test/blob/main/src/users/entities/user.entity.ts#:~:text=class%20User%20%7B-,username%3A%20string%3B,-password%3A%20string](https://github.com/networkdavit/pillicam_test/blob/main/src/users/entities/user.entity.ts#:%7E:text=class%20User%20%7B-,username%3A%20string%3B,-password%3A%20string)

You can change it.

Or you can refer to [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-nestjs/) article for JWT implementation in nest.js

Comment: Yea, about that, I just changed it before sending the code, its not username anymore, but still doesn't work,

Comment: Did you have a look at the article I mentioned? https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-nestjs/#:~:text=root%20AppModule.-,Creating%20the%20user%20module,-To%20keep%20your You can define the user schema in another way. @networkdavit

Comment: Yep, I did, still no luck but I guess ill keep trying to solve this mystery

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever gets this problem, I found a solution.
All I had to do was to add this to my local.strategy.ts file in constructor

```
super({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
});
```

The default expects a username and password, so have to modify it manually